# Laravel 5.3 - change 'guest redirect' to 'index' instead of 'login' route

Tags: laravel, redirect, laravel-5.3

Well, the basic problem is that Laravel 5.3 redirects guest users to the '/login' route, which I changed in 'app/Exceptions/Handler.php' to my index '/', because I have no login page/the login is located at the index.

Before:

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }

    // IMPORTANT LINE
    return redirect()->guest('/login');
}
```

After:

```
...
return redirect()->guest('/');
...
```

After this change an guest user gets redirected to the index file in a infinite loop, because he isn't logged in when he visits the '/' route and therefore getting redirected to '/' again.

I thought the solution would be easy, I would check the current url in the file before redirecting like this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) !== '/')
{
    return redirect ('/');
}
```

This didn't worked, so I tried it the laravel way:

```
if (!$request()->is('/'))
{
    return redirect ('/');
}
```

Same behavour/exception:

```
ErrorException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 136:
Trying to get property of non-object
```

Comment: you will need to create a DMZ controller which will handle unauthenticated users and on the view page you can check for `Auth::user()` to determine if it is an authenticated user or not

Comment: What is a DMZ controller?

Comment: what I mean by a DMZ controller is a controller that is not guarded with authentication. A controller that has no authentication

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your index route load something like your home page, so the thing is that with that change you made, you need to remove the auth middleware in your home page controller or the app will be stuck in an infinite loop like it is right now. To stick to your change you have made just comment the auth middleware in your route controller.

```
public function __construct()
  {
    // $this->middleware('auth');
  }
```

Comment: Well, I think commenting out is a bad solution. In fact I already knew, that the middleware causes the problem.

Comment: If you dont need to protect your home route or index route under your Auth middleware, whats the point of keeping that line in route controller? It doesnt make much sense to me. There are many ways to handle this problem, creating a custom middleware would be one of those, handle it from the route controller with a simple if statement would be other...